# How to extend class method

Tags: python

Both `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` are the sub-classes of `Base` class (both inherit from same `Base` class). Since `getInfo()` method is declared within `Base()` class it (this method) is shared between both A and B sub-classes. When `getInfo()` method is called it returns the value of `self.attr` variable (shared among A and B sub-classes). Now I want to "extend" this method. So when it is called via subClassA instance using `instanceA.getInfo()` **in addition to** `self.attr` it would return `self.attrA` as well. Likewise if instanceB is used: `instanceB.getInfo()` `self.attrB` is returned in addition to returning `self.attr`. How `Base()` class's method `getInfo()` can be extended so it is "customized" for both sub-classes A and B?

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.attr='Attr'

    def getInfo(self):
        info=self.getAttr()
        return info
    def getAttr(self):
        return self.attr

class SubClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClassA, self).__init__()  
        self.attrA='attrA'      
    def getAttrA(self):
        return self.attrA

class SubClassB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClassB, self).__init__()  
        self.attrB='attrB'      
    def getAttrB(self):
        return self.attrB

instanceA=SubClassA()
instanceB=SubClassB()
print instanceA.getInfo()
print instanceB.getInfo()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply define the `getInfo` method in the subclasses.  If desired, use `super` (as you are in your constructors) to get the result of the base class `getInfo()` and incorporate it as desired.

To elaborate: when given an instance `c` of some class `C`, and asked to look up an attribute `c.attr`, Python looks for the attribute in a sequence of places.  In particular, it will look in derived classes before base classes.  Thus the following code

```
class Base(object):
    def method(self):
        return "I'm a base object!"

class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        return "I'm a derived object!"

obj = Derived()
print obj.method()
```

will print "I'm a derived object!", because Python looks for `method` in `Derived`, finds it, and never checks in `Base`.

You mentioned a need to call `Base.method` in your `Derived` object.  That's where `super` comes in.  `super(Derived, self).method()` will find and call `Base.method` on `self`.  You are already doing that in your constructors.

For example:

```
class Computer(object):
    def boot_message(self):
        return 'I am a computer'

class AppleComputer(Computer):
    def boot_message(self):
        return super(AppleComputer, self).boot_message() + ' with a really shiny logo'
```

We avoid duplicating the effort in `Computer.boot_message` by taking its result and modifying it as necessary.

Note that the `super(Base, self).__init__()` line is not necessary; in general such calls are only desirable if the base class `__init__()` does work that the derived class `__init__()` wants to accomplish without code duplication, which is not the case for `object`.

Comment: But `Derived()` class's `method()` will overwrite `Base()` `method()` completely. I would have to retype entire `method()` for `Derived` from scratch. The question is how to "extend" the `method()`.

Comment: That's the purpose of `super()`.  I'll try to elaborate in my answer.

Comment: Okay.  (After fixing some typos...)

Comment: @onethreeseven Is it possible to use any local variable of `Computer.boot_message` and use it in `AppleComputer.boot_message` after `super(AppleComputer, self).boot_message()`?

Answer (score 0):

An additional option is that you can return both attributes:

```
return self.attr, self.attrA
```

Also, another approach in addition to onethreeseven's is you can extend the attr data itself with your attrA data, such as in a list or adding to a string, and return that.

Or you can call both methods you have recursively or with a decorator, which is possible as follows. Access (and thus redefine) the definition of a class directly

> You can get the original function with the **func** attribute: `ClassName.function_name = decorator(ClassName.function_name.__func__)`.

from [How can one attach a decorator to a function "after the fact" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868886/how-can-one-attach-a-decorator-to-a-function-after-the-fact-in-python)
(Martijn Pieters answering a question in the function/decorator domain)