# How can one attach a decorator to a function "after the fact" in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

The way I understand decorators of function in python (and I might be wrong), is that they are supposed to add side effects and modify the return value of a function. Now decorators are added above the function definition of the function to be decorated or by an assignment. Here is a small example:

```py
def print_args_decor(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'Arguments:', args, kwargs         # Added side-effect
        return function(*args, **kwargs)*5       # Modified return value
    return wrapper

@print_args_decor
def do_stuff(strg, n=10):
    """Repeats strg a few times."""
    return strg * n

new_decorated_func = print_args_decor(do_stuff)  # Decoration by assignment

print do_stuff('a', 2) # Output: aaaaaaaaaa
```

Now, **how does one attach a decorator to a function defined elsewhere**, ideally **retaining the original function's name and docstring** (like `functools.wraps` does)? For example, I'm importing the `sqrt()` function from Python's math module, and want to decorate it, how do I go about that?

```py
from functools import wraps
from math import sqrt

def print_args_decor(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'Arguments:', args, kwargs         # Added side-effect
        return function(*args, **kwargs)*5       # Modified return value
    return wrapper

# Decorate the sqrt() function from math module somehow
@print_args_decor #???
sqrt #???

print sqrt(9)   
# Output: 
# Arguments: ([9],) {}
# 15                   # <--- sqrt(9)*5
```

How about decorate methods within classes after the fact? How about decorating classes themselves?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You imported `sqrt` into your module, just apply the decorator there in your own global namespace:

```
sqrt = print_args_decor(sqrt)
```

This sets the name `sqrt` in your module namespace to the result of the decorator. There is no requirement that `sqrt` was originally defined in this module.

It is up to the decorator to uses the `functools.wraps()` decorator to preserve function metadata such as the name and docstring.

Decorating a class is no different in this respect:

```
ClassName = decorator(ClassName)
```

On Python 2, for *methods* you need to be careful to grab the original unbound function; easiest is to use the `method.__func__` attribute:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    ClassName.function_name = decorator(ClassName.function_name.__func__)
except AttributeError:
    # Python 3
    ClassName.function_name = decorator(ClassName.function_name)
```

I've wrapped the above in a `try...except` to make the pattern work across Python versions. The alternative is to grab the function object out of the class `__dict__` to avoid the descriptor protocol from kicking in:

```
ClassName.function_name = decorator(ClassName.__dict__['function_name'])
```

Comment: Seems simple enough, thanks. Can you add an example of decorating a class and method within a class?

Comment: @con-f-use: A decorator is *just a callable*. The `@decorator` syntax, as you already stated, just passes the decorated object to the decorator callable and replaces the name with the result. So for a class that's just `ClassName = decorator(ClassName)`.

Comment: @con-f-use: existing methods is a little more tricky, as the decorator applies to the *function object* before it becomes part of the class. You can get the original function with the `__func__` attribute: `ClassName.function_name = decorator(ClassName.function_name.__func__)`.