# python: decorate an existing method of a module

Tags: python, python-2.7

My application has many calls to request methods (get, post, put, delete). I want to tap these calls to print out debug/trace information of all calls that go out of my application.

I run everything inside a venv, so one obvious options is to go to the reqeusts module in venv and decorate the 4 methods with a function that can do the necessary logging.

Is there another way to achieve this?

```
import requests

# do some magic to install a decorative method for requests.get

requests.get('http://google.com')
```

Should result in the decorator getting calls which would do the necessary logging.

I looked into patch / flexmock / requests_mock but it appears that I need to provide an alternate implementation of the method. What I need is a way to decorate an existing method.

Comment: `requests.get = decorated(requests.get)`?

Comment: fwiw, requests has an [event framework](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks) so you don't need to monkeypatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one attach a decorator to a function "after the fact" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868886/how-can-one-attach-a-decorator-to-a-function-after-the-fact-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorator is just a function that returns another function:

```
def decorator(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

requests.get = decorator(requests.get)
requests.get('http://google.com')

(('http://google.com',), {})
<Response [200]>
```